# Drop column by name using [ without assigning name to data frame/ matrix object

Tags: r

[@Joris Meys great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605268/7941188) [to this famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name) suggests to drop columns by name using a list of names. It requires previous assignment of a name to the data frame/ matrix and using `names(df)`, or for matrices `colnames(matrix)`.

Out of curiosity, I wondered if a similar strategy is possible without assigning a name to the data frame/ matrix in a first place. I was pondering on this fact [on answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239017/create-new-data-frame-with-multiple-subsets-of-same-variable/52239589#52239589) (from where I nicked my sample data).

My suggested solution drops the column with `select` as follows:

```
bind_cols(split(df$b, df$year)) %>% select(-'1997')
```

I was first trying to use `do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year))` instead,  but this gave a matrix, and `dplyr::select` did not like that. Now I could of course *positive select*:

```
do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year))[,c('1996','1998')]
```

I could also use `subset` :

```
subset(do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year)), select = - `1997`)
```

My question is how to use `[` for 'negative selection' by name (here: dropping of `1997`), without previous assignment of the matrix/ data frame, i.e. in a one liner.

---

**data**

```
set.seed(77)
df <- data.frame(year = rep(1996:1998,3), a = runif(9), b = runif(9), e = runif(9))

# required result something like: (result from code above)   

          1996      1998
[1,] 0.4569087 0.9881951
[2,] 0.1658851 0.4475605
[3,] 0.3647157 0.7033574
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how your `df` would result in the desired output (without some extra transformation). Can you talk more about the process?

Comment: Not really an answer to the question but you could assign `NULL` to column `1997` using `"[<-"`, i.e. `bind_cols(split(df$b, df$year)) %>% \`[<-\`(., '1997', value = NULL)`

Comment: @RomanLuštrik with my above code using `subset(do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year)), select = - '1997')`. Note that I have changed `set.seed` from 88 to 77 a minute after I have originally posted the question - maybe you were very fast and have used the first data .... ?

Comment: @markus this would be a way for sure - however you are right, it is not exactly what I meant

Comment: @Sotos using `which` and the information of the original df would also be a good way, this is true. Thanks for pointing out to `cbind.data.frame`, very useful :)

Comment: How about subsetting out 1997 and reshaping the data afterwards into a long format?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for the thoughts. This is basically what @akrun did in his answer to the original question. My question is more of a theoretical nature, if a 'negative subset' by name with `[` is possible without having to assign a name to the df/matrix first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are obviously many ways to achieve that but if you just want to use the negative subset by name, then one way is to use your original dataframe to get the first position of your target and use that to remove it, i.e.

```
do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year))[,-which(df$year == '1997')[1]]
```

which gives,

> ```
>           1996      1998
> [1,] 0.4569087 0.9881951
> [2,] 0.1658851 0.4475605
> [3,] 0.3647157 0.7033574
> ```

**NOTE 1:** Your initial data frame must be sorted on `year`

**NOTE 2:** You can use `cbind.data.frame` to get your output as a data frame

Comment: I think this is a good idea - but somehow it leaves me unsatisfied that it would require the information of the previous data structure and moreover be dependent on correct sorting. It is one very good and interesting answer to the question. I will wait with accepting it as *the* answer though if you don’t mind.

Comment: @Tjebo No problem. i m also curious to see other options

Comment: Although not really what I intended, you have answered this question correctly. I have made a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52401049/7941188) Would be happy to have your thoughts on it :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't select columns by name, but what if you filter the rows in `split` first using `[` for negative selection.

```
do.call(cbind, split(df[-which(df$year == 1997),"b"], df[-which(df$year == 1997), "year"]))
#>           1996      1998
#> [1,] 0.4569087 0.9881951
#> [2,] 0.1658851 0.4475605
#> [3,] 0.3647157 0.7033574
```

or maybe a super long one-liner for negative column indexing

```
do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year))[,-which(colnames(do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year))) == "1997")]
#>           1996      1998
#> [1,] 0.4569087 0.9881951
#> [2,] 0.1658851 0.4475605
#> [3,] 0.3647157 0.7033574
```

Although, you could condense it with a pipe

```
do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year)) %>%  .[,-which(colnames(.) == "1997")]
#>           1996      1998
#> [1,] 0.4569087 0.9881951
#> [2,] 0.1658851 0.4475605
#> [3,] 0.3647157 0.7033574
```

Comment: thanks for the thoughts! These are all good ideas, and your code is working for this example. But it was actually meant more as a theoretical consideration if this works in general, rather than for this particular example (should have clarified this better, will try to improve the wording of the question), - ideally without the need of using the previously defined / assigned data frame as help.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

In one line calling an anonymous function

```
(function(df) df[!names(df) %in% c('1997')])(as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year))))
#       1996      1998
#1 0.2309219 0.9199970
#2 0.7308675 0.1856637
#3 0.6101509 0.6482355
```

The `as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, split(df$b, df$year)))` converts into the argument of the anonymous function. I think this option does not require to assign the names and don't depend in the information of the previously object, since the `names(df)` inside the anonymous function definition use the names of the argument.

But we can declare it as a function an use the pipe `|>` operator to make it more readable:

```
dropByNames <- function(df, toDrop) df[!names(df) %in% toDrop]

df |>
  with(split(b, year)) |>
  list2DF()|>
  dropByNames('1997')
```